# unable to compile linux kernel version 3.16

Tags: linux, makefile, build, linux-kernel, linker

I'm trying to compile the linux kernel version 3.16, but it gives me linker errors.

I tried running `make menuconfig`, `make defconfig` individually, and then `make -no-pie` (this kernel doesn't support position independent code so I have to append this flag)
I also tried `make mrproper`, `make clean`, redoing all these steps in different variations, it fails everytime at this issue.

I took the kernel code from different sources just to be sure that I'm not running a faulty source code, and ended up trying

- get the code from linux-stable git and checking out to my desired version
- download a tarball from kernel.org for this specific version
- get the source code from debian repositories

but no matter which source I use, it always fails with this issue.

```
set -e;  echo '  LINK    vmlinux'; /bin/sh scripts/link-vmlinux.sh ld -m elf_x86_64 --build-id  -X; echo 'cmd_vmlinux := /bin/sh scripts/link-vmlinux.sh ld -m elf_x86_64 --build-id  -X' > ./.vmlinux.cmd
  LINK    vmlinux
  LD      vmlinux.o
ld: cannot find arch/x86/kernel/head_64.o: No such file or directory
ld: cannot find arch/x86/kernel/head64.o: No such file or directory
ld: cannot find arch/x86/kernel/head.o: No such file or directory
ld: cannot find init/built-in.o: No such file or directory
ld: cannot find usr/built-in.o: No such file or directory
ld: cannot find arch/x86/built-in.o: No such file or directory
ld: cannot find kernel/built-in.o: No such file or directory
ld: cannot find mm/built-in.o: No such file or directory
ld: cannot find fs/built-in.o: No such file or directory
ld: cannot find ipc/built-in.o: No such file or directory
ld: cannot find security/built-in.o: No such file or directory
ld: cannot find crypto/built-in.o: No such file or directory
ld: cannot find block/built-in.o: No such file or directory
ld: cannot find lib/lib.a: No such file or directory
ld: cannot find arch/x86/lib/lib.a: No such file or directory
ld: cannot find lib/built-in.o: No such file or directory
ld: cannot find arch/x86/lib/built-in.o: No such file or directory
ld: cannot find drivers/built-in.o: No such file or directory
ld: cannot find sound/built-in.o: No such file or directory
ld: cannot find arch/x86/pci/built-in.o: No such file or directory
ld: cannot find arch/x86/power/built-in.o: No such file or directory
ld: cannot find arch/x86/video/built-in.o: No such file or directory
ld: cannot find net/built-in.o: No such file or directory
make: *** [Makefile:893: vmlinux] Error 1
```

Comment: Any specific reason you can't build newest kernel?

Comment: I also getting same issue. Have you found why this happens? @Blingu